# Save Query Result as csv file on server under specific folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to save sql server 2008 query result to server itself and store file link in another table so whenever i want i can download the file, without re executing the query.

I am using asp.net with C# as front end.

in front end it is like. `Enter Area Code`
user enters area code and click on submit, it will search all record with the same area code in database and save it in csv file on server.

i am using following code.

```
select * from mytablename where area_code=21
```

save this result on my server.

Comment: Are you certain that the query is your bottleneck?  That seems pretty straight forward, with the proper indexing it should be a lot faster than pulling a csv file and parsing it.  Remember [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: no but i want to save it csv file and values would be different from time to time, so i need to have snapshot of it in the form of csv file on server

Comment: if the values change, what would trigger you to update the csv? (xml would be better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "select * from mytablename where area_code=21" queryout c:\bcp\[filename] -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

execute this query you have to set path for write file.
currently in this query you have to create a "bcp" folder in "C:\ "Drive .

Comment: hi i tried this it says
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'cur_activity'.
where cur_activity is my table name

Answer (score 1):

```
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew);
            StreamWriter CsvfileWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
            //This Block of code for getting the Table Headers

            for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                tableColumns.Columns.Add(dr.GetName(i));
            }
            CsvfileWriter.WriteLine(tableColumns.Columns.ConcatUsing(","));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0},", dr[i]);
                }
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
            CsvfileWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Save the path name is table.

Answer (score -1):

Use LinqToCSV and write the file to the server.
Writing should be straight forward using the built in methods of LinqToCSV.
Then store the file name in the table.